# Key derivation function for random bytes?

Tags: encryption, password-encryption, pbkdf2

I know KDF (Key derivation function) are used to stretch user passwords, which are basically not suitable to be used as keys in cryptographic algorithms.

But what if I create a random key (random 32 bytes), do I still need to use KDF on it to ensure proper encryption?

Comment: More suitable for crypto.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A KDF is typically used for deriving cryptographic keys from things like passphrases, which as you correctly say are not suitable for direct use. But they are also used for deriving additional keys from a master key, which depending on your overall scheme, might be useful.

Suppose you used a key agreement protocol where both parties ended up with a random shared secret. You could use a KDF to derive a key for encryption, and one for message integrity (for example, an HMAC key).

From [NIST SP800-108](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-108/sp800-108.pdf):

> When parties share a secret symmetric key (e.g., upon a successful
>   execution of a key-  establishment scheme as specified in [1](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-108/sp800-108.pdf) and
>   [2]), it is often the case that additional keys will be needed (e.g.
>   as described in [3]). Separate keys may be needed for different 
>   cryptographic purposes – for example, one  key may be required for an
>   encryption  algorithm, while another key is intended for use by an
>   integrity protection algorithm, such  as a message authentication
>   code. At other times, the distinct keys required by multiple  entities
>   may be generated by a trusted party from a single master key.  Key
>   derivation  functions are used to derive such keys.

The short answer is, no, you don't *need* to use a KDF, assuming your key generation is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this document at all